# Determining number of unique schemas in multiple XML files

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a big stack of XML files with different schemas. Many of the files share the same schema, but I don't know how many types exist. How can I determine (1) the number of schemas and (2) the schema of each file? Ideally, the output would allow me to concatenate all files of type 1, all files of type 2, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an confused understanding of what a "schema" is. A schema is collection of schema components (such as types, element declarations etc), and given a set of 1000 types, the question of how many distinct schemas you have is pretty meaningless - I guess the answer is some kind of combinatorial function that considers all possible subsets of the 1000.

A more meaningful question might be how many distinct top-level elements there are in your instances. You can determine that even without any schema information: it's just

```
count(distinct-values(collecion("XYZ")/node-name(*)))
```